# Drag rows out of a multiselect DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I'm having a problem dragging rows out of a datagridview. The grid has the property multiselect = true and every time I select the rows I want to drag out and then left click on the grid again, the selected rows disappear.
Anyone got a solution / a working example? Thx.

Comment: When I tried this recently I ended out using a ListView in details view: still not ideal though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is obviously not as easy as I thought.
Ended up buying DevExpress.